# List Comprehension - Split List Item by size of element, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have below List, I want to split it, if size of list item > 2 as separate element and if size less than 2 then as sublist. I have written below script and working. But how to achieve using List Comprehension or any lambda expression.

```
My_List = ['ABC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD']

New_Chunks = []
New_Chunks2 = []
for Item in My_List:
    if len(Item) > 2:
        New_Chunks.append(Item)
    else:
        New_Chunks2.append(Item)

New_Chunks.append(New_Chunks2)

Result: ['ABC', 'ABCD', ['A', 'AB']]
```

Comment: List comprehensions aren't suitable for adding to multiple different lists at the same time, and `lambda`s themselves won't be useful unless they're paired with a tool like `map` (although that would be an abuse of `map`). There *may* be an `itertool` that can make use of a `lambda` to help here, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for reply; any better solution ?

Comment: I think what you have here is fine (besides the naming issues). I think anything else would likely be an overcomplication of a relatively simple problem. You could use a conditional expression to neaten it a bit, but it wouldn't be a massive change.

Comment: If you really want, you can:
```a = [item for item in My_List if len(item) > 2]
b = [item for item in My_List if len(item) <= 2]
a.append(b)
```

Comment: @OrY That does a lot of extra work (iterating the list twice, calculating the length of each item twice) with no significant benefit.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/2c21ba2c11f3dba25d32ce78e525f56f)? Although it doesn't use either tool that you want, and the gains are minimal, if any. @OrY The problem with that is, it requires two iterations of `My_List` to do.

Comment: @Carcigenicate; thanks for discussion

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine for this case, if you really really wanna make it shorter you can do something like

```py
My_List = ['ABC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD']

New_Chunks = []
New_Chunks2 = []
# or in one line New_Chunks, New_Chunks2 = [], []
for Item in My_List:
    (New_Chunks2, New_Chunks)[len(Item) > 2].append(Item)
# or do it in one line as [(New_Chunks2, New_Chunks)[len(Item) > 2].append(Item) for Item in My_List]

New_Chunks.append(New_Chunks2)
```

Result: `['ABC', 'ABCD', ['A', 'AB']]`

but yours is more readable

## Even Shorter

> I'm just having fun here, please don't do this

```py
My_List = ['ABC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD']

New_Chunks2 = []
New_Chunks = [New_Chunks2]
[(New_Chunks2, New_Chunks)[len(Item) > 2].append(Item) for Item in My_List]
```

Result: `[['A', 'AB'], 'ABC', 'ABCD']`

Comment: @Jimmer, Thanks for the try

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
my_list = ['ABC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD']
number_list1 = []
number_list2 = []
[number_list1.append(x) if len(x) > 2 else number_list2.append(x) for x in my_list] 
number_list1.append(number_list2)
print(number_list1)
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'ABCD', ['A', 'AB']]
```

Or this:

```
my_list = ['ABC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABCD']
number_list = [x for x in my_list if len(x) > 2 ]
number_list2 = [x for x in my_list if len(x) <= 2 ]
number_list.append(number_list2)
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'ABCD', ['A', 'AB']]
```

Comment: This one will add None objects to the list, the output would be `['ABC', None, None, 'ABCD', ['A', 'AB']]`